# Not able to implement pivot on data stored in dataset

Tags: c#, sql-server, dataset, pivot-table

I have dataset which contains below result set:

[image]

I want result as below :

[image]

I tried using Pivot but failed. I am trying to do it in C# code in .cs file not in sql server procedure.

This is what I tried in SQL Server. It is not giving desired result.

```
    Declare @CourseID int
 Declare @SemID int
 Set @SemID=1
 Set @CourseID=1
 DECLARE @values varchar(max);
SET @values = '';
 If(@SemID=0)
    BEGIN
        SELECT @values = @values +'['+ CAST(PurPose AS varchar(max))+ ']' + ','
        FROM tbFee Where CourseID=@CourseID
        SET @values = SUBSTRING(@values, 1, Len(@values) - 1)
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT @values = @values +'['+ CAST(PurPose AS varchar(max))+ ']' + ','
        FROM tbFee Where SemID=@SemID
        SET @values = SUBSTRING(@values, 1, Len(@values) - 1)
    END

 Declare @st nvarchar(max)
 set @st='''Not Available''';
 declare @q nvarchar(max)
set @q = '
 Select * from(

SELECT     dbo.tbStudent.Name, dbo.tbStudent.RegNo, dbo.tbFee.PID, dbo.tbFee.Purpose, dbo.tbFee.AmountPaid, dbo.tbFee.StudentID, dbo.tbFee.Date, dbo.tbFee.FeeID, 
                      dbo.tbFee.SemID, dbo.tbFee.CourseID, dbo.tbFee.ModeOfPayment, dbo.tbFee.CheckNo, dbo.tbFee.DDNo, dbo.tbFee.HostelDDNo, dbo.tbFee.FRID, 
                      dbo.tbStudent.Parentage, dbo.tbCourse.Name AS Course, ISNULL(dbo.tbSemester.SemName, ' + @st +') AS Semester
FROM         dbo.tbFee INNER JOIN
                      dbo.tbStudent ON dbo.tbFee.StudentID = dbo.tbStudent.StudentID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.tbCourse ON dbo.tbFee.CourseID = dbo.tbCourse.CourseID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.tbSemester ON dbo.tbFee.SemID = dbo.tbSemester.SemID 
          ) as x
          pivot (
    max(AmountPaid)
    for Purpose in (' + @values + ')
) as pvt
'

exec (@q)
```

Below code gives me the first result set which i need to populate in dataset and this part is fine.

```
  SELECT     dbo.tbStudent.Name, dbo.tbStudent.RegNo, dbo.tbFee.PID, dbo.tbFee.Purpose, dbo.tbFee.AmountPaid, dbo.tbFee.StudentID, dbo.tbFee.Date, dbo.tbFee.FeeID, 
                      dbo.tbFee.SemID, dbo.tbFee.CourseID, dbo.tbFee.ModeOfPayment, dbo.tbFee.CheckNo, dbo.tbFee.DDNo, dbo.tbFee.HostelDDNo, dbo.tbFee.FRID, 
                      dbo.tbStudent.Parentage, dbo.tbCourse.Name AS Course, ISNULL(dbo.tbSemester.SemName, ' + @st +') AS Semester
FROM         dbo.tbFee INNER JOIN
                      dbo.tbStudent ON dbo.tbFee.StudentID = dbo.tbStudent.StudentID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.tbCourse ON dbo.tbFee.CourseID = dbo.tbCourse.CourseID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.tbSemester ON dbo.tbFee.SemID = dbo.tbSemester.SemID
```

First I need to get result set as I have shown in 2nd table, plus I need to do it in c# code on data set which will contain first table result

Comment: `I tried using Pivot but failed.`..Show us what you have tried?

Comment: ok i will, just a minute